# Has Sitecore 8 built-in support for MVC areas?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

Is Sitecore 8 has built-in support for MVC areas? Or do I still need to install sitecore plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting Kevin Brechbühl (from [The Sitecore MVC puzzle](http://sitecore.unic.com/2015/06/24/the-sitecore-mvc-puzzle)):

> Sitecore has no support for areas out of the box, but there are multiple solutions available for integrate them in your solutions:
>
> > 1. [Resolve the area in the mvc.renderRendering-pipeline](http://bit.ly/MvcAreas1)
> > 2. [Use a custom ControllerRunner and a custom Renderer](http://bit.ly/MvcAreas2)
> > 3. [Resolve the area by the  configurations](http://bit.ly/MvcAreas3)
>
> We also saw that Sitecore is working on a solution to integrate areas into the core. Rumor has it that they will integrate a similar pattern as `BrainJocks` does with the `mvc.renderRendering` pipeline.